# Error creating bean with name dataSource defined

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

I am trying to configured datasource but getting below exception not what is the root cause.

I have postgresql jar. Posting the full log.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/truecom/portal/config/RDataBaseConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties]: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:464)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
at com.truecom.portal.PortalBackendApp.main(PortalBackendApp.java:64)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:478)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
```

application-dev.yml configuration.

```
spring:
devtools:
    restart:
        enabled: true
    livereload:
        enabled: false # we use gulp + BrowserSync for livereload
datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:1232/test
    username: test
    password: tes
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
```

Java class configuration.

```
@Configuration
```

RDataBaseConfiguration 
{

```
@Inject
private Environment env;


@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
public DataSource dataSource(DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties) {
    log.debug("Configuring Datasource");
    if (dataSourceProperties.getUrl() == null) {
        log.error("Your database connection pool configuration is incorrect! The application" +
                " cannot start. Please check your Spring profile, current profiles are: {}",
            Arrays.toString(env.getActiveProfiles()));

        throw new ApplicationContextException("Database connection pool is not configured correctly");
    }
    HikariDataSource hikariDataSource =  (HikariDataSource) DataSourceBuilder
            .create(dataSourceProperties.getClassLoader())
            .type(HikariDataSource.class)
            .driverClassName(dataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName())
            .url(dataSourceProperties.getUrl())
            .username(dataSourceProperties.getUsername())
            .password(dataSourceProperties.getPassword())
            .build();

    return hikariDataSource;


}
```

}

Comment: if that is really your yaml file (which should be prefixed `yml` not `yam`) your indentation is wrong.

Comment: updated question. thanks for inform.

Comment: Got it. Missing dependency <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>